# add TinyMCE editor in child-row of datatables

Tags: datatables, tinymce

I am wondering whether TinyMCE is able to work in a child row. In my case, I have a child-row for each row, and I want to add a TinyMCE editor in each child-row.

[image]

The problem is that, as shown in screenshot, TinyMCE does not work when child-row is shown, I can only see a textarea there without TinyMCE icons, toolbar etc. I simplified the relevant code and attached below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
  selector: '#email_editor',
  statusbar: false,
  menubar: false,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: "advlist lists image textcolor code paste",
  height: 150,
  toolbar: 'formatselect outdent indent bold italic strikethrough | 
  forecolor backcolor |
  alignleft aligncenter alignright | numlist bullist'
  });
</script>

$('#labmeetingrecord tbody').on('click', 'td.edit_button', function ()    {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row( tr );
  if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
  row.child.hide();
  tr.removeClass('shown');
  }
  else {
  row.child(format()).show(); //format(row.data())
  $(row.child()).addClass('smalltable');
  tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});

function format ( ) {
return
  '<table width:100%  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="child_table" 
  border="0">' +
  '<tr>'+
  '<td>'+
  '<textarea id="email_editor"></textarea>'+
  '</td>'+
  '</tr>'+
  '</table>';
```

finally it worked I attached the snapshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice two things here...

1 - You appear to be inserting the `textarea` with a hard coded ID.  An ID should be unique within the page so if you will be running your format code more than once you will have issues.

2 - You need to run `tinymce.init({})` after the HTML is added to the page.  You above code seems to run the `init` method but its not tied to the insertion of the HTML to the page.  You don't want to run the `init` until after the `textarea` is part of the DOM.

Comment: WORKED!   both your suggestion are important and it would not be working without any of the two!  Thanks!